# Inverting 3d rotation sequence

Tags: rotation, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

I have a transformation matrix constructed as
`H = Rz * Ry * Rx`. So rotations are performed in xyz order.

Now, given rotation angles around x, y, and z axes, is there a way to find rotation angles to perform inverse operation, such that

v = Rz * Ry * Rx * v0

v0 = Rz' * Ry' * Rx' * v

Just for completion sake. In the end I extracted the Euler angles from transformation matrix as described in:

Computing Euler angles from a rotation matrix - Gregory G. Slabaugh

Answer (score 4):

If your matrices are purely rotation (i.e. no translation), the inverse is simply the transpose:

> R<sup>-1</sup> = R<sup>T</sup>

If your transformation includes translation like so:

```
A = 
| R  T |  
| 0  1 |
```

Then use the transpose of the rotation matrix as above and for the translation portion, use:

> T<sup>-1</sup> = -R<sup>T</sup>T

Then

> A<sup>-1</sup> =
>   | R<sup>-1</sup> T<sup>-1</sup> |
>   |      0      1     |

Also note that you will have to do the inverse rotations in the inverse order:

> v<sub>0</sub> = R<sub>x</sub><sup>-1</sup> * R<sub>y</sub><sup>-1</sup> * R<sub>z</sub><sup>-1</sup> * v

Comment: Might be, that my question is unclear. I have rotation angles for constructing initial transformation matrix. What i need, however, is to find another set of rotation angles that will create inverse transformation matrix doing the rotations in the same order. Basically Rz * Ry * Rx = (Rz' * Ry' * Rx')^-1

Comment: If I understand you, then you just need the first line of my answer with R = (Rz * Ry * Rx).

Comment: Okay, this obviously didn't convince you. Please post examples of your rotation matrices, the code to generate them, and what you hope to achieve.